# How do I authenticate JWT token and grab claims from JWT token in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, jwt

I am trying to wrap my head around the authentication method of JWT. I have loaded composer and Firebase into my server.

I have a login.php page and a dashboard.php page. Currently, the users can click the login button, go to the login page via Azure B2C, then are redirected back to the dashboard.php page with a JWT Token. My goal is to authenticate the token, and then grab the users first_name from the claims. In addition, I am wondering if the "key" in the token header is the same key I use in my script or is this a separate key from within the B2C system?

The code I have below seems to only want to send users back to the login.php page.

```
require_once "/home/mydirectory/vendor/autoload.php";

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) { 
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;
} else {
if (! preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches)) {
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
 exit;
}
 }
  $retrievedToken = $matches[1];
  $issuer = 'https://example.org/lettersnumbers/v2.0/';
  $key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  $token = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($retrieveToken, $key, ['HS256']);
  $now = new DateTimeImmutable();

  if ($token->iss !== $issuer || $token->nbf > $now->getTimestamp() || $token->exp < $now->getTimestamp())
  {
 header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
 exit;
 }
```

I also have this added in my htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$ 
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```